# JQUERY-ui dialog x button function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using the [jquery-ui dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).
My problem is upon clicking the x button to close the dialog, i also need to perform the cancel() function.

How can I do this?

```
var content = 
{
    autoOpen    : false,
    modal       : true,
    width       : 350,
    minHeight   : 50,
    height      : 350,
    position    : "center",
    resizable   : false,
    draggable   : false,
    close       : function () {$(".privacy_modal").prop("checked", false);},
    buttons: 
    {
        "Cancel": function cancel() 
        { 
            $(".privacy_modal").prop("checked", false); $(this).dialog("close"); 
        },
        "Accept": function accept() 
        {
            $(".privacy_modal").prop("checked", true); $(this).dialog("close"); 
        }
    }
};
```

[image: TEST]

NOTE: Using close doesn't solve my problem because it overrides the function when i clicked the accept button

Comment: Hiya, sup man, you mean when user click `X` you want cancel function to be called?

Comment: function cancel() { alert("test");},

Comment: Cool, yep, see my post below with Demo, hope it helps `beforeClose` is a very good APi for this use which might come handy, `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a third-party variable (bAccepts which is False by default) and third-party method.

When user accepts:

- Set bAccepts to True

When user cancels:

- Set bAccepts to False

When onClose is fired, call the method doClose() which does the following:

- if bAccepts is True => accept
- else => cancel

Here is some un-tested psuedo-code. See [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/46ZNP/4/).

```
var bAccepts = false;
var content = {
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    modal       : true,
                    width       : 350,
                    minHeight   : 50,
                    height      : 350,
                    position    : "center",
                    resizable   : false,
                    draggable   : false,
                    close       : function () { if (bAccepts) {...} else {...} },
                    buttons: {
                        "Cancel": function cancel() { bAccepts = false; $(this).dialog("close");},
                        "Accept": function accept() { bAccepts = true; $(this).dialog("close");}
             }
};
```

Comment: Hiya bruv, just an idea we can use `beforeClose` like below demo : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-beforeClose that might suffice. cheerios `:)`

Comment: @newbie I've updated answer with working code. See working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6deP4/

Comment: @JohnRiche bro `:)` lol you jsfiddle only contains my change I reckon you forgot to add yours, just reminding lol :P

Comment: @JohnRiche ha ha yes now its what your post depicts :P Cool cool! Just a minor addition: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-close **Note** `This event is triggered when the dialog is closed.` have nice one bruv!

Comment: @JohnRiche, your code works. BUt the checkbox is being checked with a delay. The dialog box is already prepared before the bAccepts variable is changed. Thank you.

Comment: @newbie Try using beforeClose instead of close, it will happen sooner.

Comment: @jobjbar's solution works well, but has a small bug. After click accept, re-opening the dialog box, and then clicking the X, the box shows an accept message instead of a cancel message. The variable needs to be reset. I took advantage of the open method to reset the bAccepts variable. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/puddinman13/2dz8P/1/

Answer (score 3):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ea6Hm/1/

You can use : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-beforeClose

using `beforeClose` you can call any function you want to invoke before the Dialog box close.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theLink').click(function() {
        $("#forgot-dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#forgot-dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 255,
        width: 300,
        beforeClose: function() {
            alert("Do whatever before Close");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Retrieve": function() {
                document.forms["forgotform"].submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
    });


});​
```

Comment: If the user wants to stay on the current page, this won't work: you won't be able to close the dialog without triggering the beforeClose event.

Comment: Hiya @JohnRiche I reckon this will work because `beforeClose` = `This event is triggered when a dialog attempts to close.` hence beforeClose event will trigger whatever funtio s/he is calling, anyhoo OP might be able to throw more light on that context, but demo should be clear, Cheers for comment,

Comment: Yes, beforeClose and close will be called when dialog is closed, but OP wanted to have the same action done when Cancel button is clicked and when X close button is clicked: this can be achieved with a third party variable, see my answer.

Comment: @JohnRiche Yep, correct and demo works accordingly, You can see in **demo** again that when you click **cancel** `beforeClose` will invoke. i.e. in any case when dialog will close `beforeClose` will come handy hence less convoluted code. let me know if its not clear bruv `:)`

Comment: Right but the way you handle "Accept" (Retrieve in your demo) is by leaving the page, therefore you do not close the dialog. I don't think this is the ideal solution if the OP wants to stay on the page.

Comment: @JohnRiche `:))` I think the function invoke `beforeClose` should be a right solution as, Ofcourse Accept code for OP is different; in this case s/he wants to tackle `beforeClose` functionality.

Comment: Hi! The problem is I need to close the dialog box again upon clicking the accept button. That's why It is not working. See my code again. Thank you.